# Android RemoteViews: setImageViewResource() vs setImageViewUri() vs setImageViewBitmap()

Tags: android, image, memory, bitmap, android-widget

The following 3 methods (from `RemoteViews` class) can be used to update an image on a Home Screen widget, on Android:

```
setImageViewResource (int viewId, int srcId)
setImageViewUri (int viewId, Uri uri)
setImageViewBitmap (int viewId, Bitmap bitmap)
```

But after lot of research, I found that `setImageViewUri()` is the best one to use, to avoid the error `"**!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!**"` that can happen when updating the widget. But why is this the case? I couldn't find any proper reason or JavaDoc documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Some people recommend using setImageViewUri() to reduce the risk of freezing the widgets on the Home Screen. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28216#c102